# how to plot ray between 2 dots?

Tags: pine-script

how do i plot ray instead of line here?

```
plot(series = wtFractalTop ? wt2[2] : na, title = 'WT Bearish Divergence', color = wtBearDivColor, linewidth = 2, offset = -2)
plot(series = wtFractalBot ? wt2[2] : na, title = 'WT Bullish Divergence', color = wtBullDivColor, linewidth = 2, offset = -2)
```

[indicator](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4fE2H.png) in this indicator red lines betweet tops shows divergences, i wanna make them to draw a ray instead of line to see when that ray crosses 0 line (it doesnt show)

Answer (score 0):

```
var line wtBearDivRay = na
if wtFractalTop
   wtBearDivRay := line.new(x1=bar_index-2, y1=wt2[2], 
   x2=bar_index, y2=wt2[2], extend=extend.right, color=wtBearDivColor, width=2)
   line.delete(wtBearDivRay[1])
else
   line.delete(wtBearDivRay)

var line wtBullDivRay = na
if wtFractalBot
   wtBullDivRay := line.new(x1=bar_index-2, y1=wt2[2], x2=bar_index, y2=wt2[2], extend=extend.right, color=wtBullDivColor, width=2)
   line.delete(wtBullDivRay[1])
else
   line.delete(wtBullDivRay)
```

Plot a ray instead of a line, you can use the `line.new()` function in `TradingView`.

Code creates two variables `wtBearDivRay` and `wtBullDivRay` to hold the lines.

Then, for each line, it checks if the corresponding fractal exists `(wtFractalTop or wtFractalBot)`, and if it does, it draws a new ray from two bars ago `(bar_index-2)` to the current bar `(bar_index)`.

The `extend=extend.right` parameter tells `TradingView` to extend the ray to the right of the chart, and the `width=2` parameter sets the line width to `2` pixels.

Finally, if the fractal doesn't exist, it deletes the line.